# Paypal API : Mass Pay uncomprehensible error

Tags: paypal, masspay

I'm trying to get MassPay working on my website. Here's my code:
http://pastebin.com/rNGzXrq0

But it's uncomprehensible, as it gives me the error response "the number of input records is less than or equal to zero" even If there is 2 input records in the request.

How can I solve this ?

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed you have

```
'L_ATM0' => '5.00',
```

It should be

```
'L_AMT0' => '5.00',
```

Comment: @maxko87 Uhm... `ATM` is not the same as `AMT`, no?

Answer (score 0):

The full list of PayPal API error messages [can be found here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errors/#10000-to-10099).

The "long message" that you're receiving from the API is very poorly worded to the point of being almost useless.

Thankfully, the "short message" is a lot more helpful:

```
Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.
```

So the error in question is related to a bad argument being passed.